# How do I leave a comment (phpdoc) at the end of a line when forming in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm

Sometimes it is necessary to leave a link or other information at the end of a line, especially relevant in configuration arrays. But PhpStorm moves this comment to a new line.

I want to see like this

```php
[
    'configFoo' => ['some' => true], /** @see Foo::some */
    'configBar' => ['baz' => true] /** @see Bar::baz */
]
    
//...
$a = 42; /** @link https://fakewikipedia.com/The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life */
$b = 1; /** @see ExternalDocumentation */
```

But PhpStorm does as follows

```php
[
    'configFoo' => ['some' => true], 
    /** @see Foo::some */
    'configBar' => ['baz' => true] 
    /** @see Bar::baz */
]
    
//...
$a = 42;
/** @link https://fakewikipedia.com/The_Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life */
$b = 1;
/** @see ExternalDocumentation */
```

I can't find an option to disable this formatting. Is it possible?

Comment: This is not valid PHPDoc usage - please see [PSR-5: PHPDoc: 4. Basic Principles](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#4-basic-principles): `A DocBlock MUST directly precede a "Structural Element"`

Comment: @EugeneMorozov . course it's very bad, but is it possible to disable formatting?

Comment: Under which conditions does this formatting occurs? On file save? On 'Reformat' action? Please provide more information and then I can take a look again if I can help you.

Comment: @WebDevPassion when formatting a file

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can't disable formatting for this particular case only